# Extract date from timestamp in Impala

Tags: datetime, impala

I want to extract date from the timestamp in Impala, dates are present in column activation

Activation_time
2023-04-13 08:49:53.004

I tried to use from_timestamp(activation_time,'yyyy-mm-dd') as act_time

But the output I got is 2023-49-13

what I want in output is
2023-04-13

Answer (score 1):

Best way with timestamp type format is to use `year()` function.

```
select year(activation_time) as year_act_time from {your_table}
```

You can extract almost everything using like:
`year()`, `month()`, `day()`, `hour()`, `min()`, `sec()`

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_date('2023-04-13 08:49:53.004') as date_value
```